# c++ - How can I inject icon resource in executable

Tags: c++, c, winapi, resources

I am looking to inject an icon (.ico) file into an executable that does not have any resources.

**pseudo C++ code:**

```
read("target.exe");
AddResourceA(LPCSTR("icon.ico"));
save("target1.exe");
```

This code should load the executable, inject the icon, then save the new executable.

Comment: ["sudo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) is a Unix command that executes a command as another user. ["pseudo-"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-) is a prefix (from the Greek 'ψευδής').

Comment: Of old tools like `resedit` did that (if I recall the name correctly). If you want to make it from scratch, then one approach is to google "msdn resource functions", then click on the one function that looks likely.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't explicitly state this: Resources are replaced/updated in-place. You'll have to make a copy of the executable first, and work with that instead of your proposed sequenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you are probably looking for are:

[BeginUpdateResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[UpdateResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049(v=vs.85).aspx)

[EndUpateResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648032(v=vs.85).aspx)

There should be plenty of examples of usage of these functions if you did a web search.

Comment: What's the point of writing this answer? Why not think first.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If you have to ask, stackoverflow is the wrong site for you.

Comment: @IInspectable: As have often happened, you didn't stop to reflect, and so did not get the point.

Comment: @IInspectable, you do have problem with almost everyone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640434/background-combobox-on-gradient-parent-window/37651395#37651395
How my answer there is bad than this one which is giving the reference only? I gave the hints there, not set of functions on a closed question. Don't have double standards @IInspectable

Comment: And hey, Paul, I've no grudge against you man!

Comment: @Ajay: This answer is giving links to a working solution. Your linked answer is handing out speculation from the clueless. No double standards there. While this answer may not get my upvote, yours certainly deserves my downvote. At any rate, don't hijack an unrelated Q&A to make a point that ain't.